# CurrentDateTime doesn't work in select record formula on the server

Tags: parameters, server, crystal-reports

I have a report where I have an optional Date parameter, and use the current date if the parameter is not set. I have the following code in the Record selection formula:

```
dateTimeVar refDate := CurrentDateTime
If HasValue({?DateParam}) refDate := {?DateParam}
```

This works as intended in Crystal Reports (the application), but when I upload the report to the Crystal Server the same code errors out:

```
Error in formula Record Selection: 'dateTimeVar refDate := CurrentDateTime;' A DateTime value is required here. Details: errorKind
```

I have to make a guess at the english error text, since our server installation is in the Dutch localisation, so the actual error returned is in Dutch.
I googled extensively on the error, but nothing appropriate comes up.
Crystal Report version: 2016 SP3, 14.2.3.2132
Crystal Server version: SAP BusinessObjects BI-platform 4.2 SP3 14.2.3.2132

Answer (score 0):

can you try this in the record selection formula

```
if hasvalue({?DateParam}) then 
 yourdatefield =yourdatefield
else    
  yourdatefield =   CurrentDateTime
```

Comment: If I try that, the error becomes:

    Error in formula Record Selection: 'If HasValue({?Datum})' A number, Currency amount, Boolean value, Date, Time, DateTime or string is expected here. Details: errorKind.

It seems that evaluation of fields and functions doesn't work in the server (everything works fine in the CR application).

Comment: ('Datum' is my parameter field).

Comment: I think your parameter is not working when you pass the value. Try a simple CR object to display your parameter value

Comment: I don't want to display the value, I want to use it in the record selection formula to limit the selected records to the date (or today if no parameter was supplied). This works exactly as intended in the CR application, so why doesn't it work in the server?

Comment: We will need to test if the parameter value can be passed by the application... if you dont test then goodluck

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. When I put a CR object on the report with the Date parameter in it, it displays the supplied value of the parameter or empty if no value was supplied (in the CR application). When I upload the report to the server and try to schedule it there, I get a similar error as before on the first line 'dateTimeVar refDate := CurrentDateTime;' A string is required here.

Comment: Specifically: I get this error in the formula Record Selection, the report never runs. When I remove the formula, the report will run, but contains all records returned from the DB (as you'd expect).

Comment: Are you saying you've tried my formula either hasvalue or isnull did not work?

Comment: I have tried various different versions of the formula, including your suggestions. The problem seems to be that the formula never gets executed on the CR server. The report just fails with an error message on the first line of the formula.